# Calculation of an appropriate sample size

Tags: sample-size

I am conducting a project in which we are studying a specific biomarker for asthma. This biomarker normally appears in 63% of the population. I would like to know what would be the sample size to analyse to obtain 63% of patients with this biomarker.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you know that 63 % of the population have this trait then why do you need a sample? What exactly is your research question?

Comment: I am sorry if the question seems very basic, but I would like to be sure of the steps I am taking. Based on other articles we have seen that this biomarker is represented by 63% in the population with asthma. We are considering a project that contains an optimal sample size to obtain this percentage. So I would like to know what would be the optimal size of asthma patients to obtain that percentage. Thank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. IF the population indeed has a trait in 63 % of the individuals then any sample will give you this estimate, or at least it will converge to this number asymptotically, that is a property of the mean. So it looks like something is missing here, I think you are missing some information about the variance of this estimate, that is how close you want this estimate to be to this specific value.